# I am getting error when trying to get integer out of TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is my code

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int i  = int.Parse(TextBox.Text);
    }
```

it gives me "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TextBox.Text'" error

Comment: What's the actual variable name of your text box control? If it's actually `TextBox`, please don't do that - it's easy to make conflicts with existing classes.

Comment: When you get this issue addressed, the next one, possibly, is doing `int.Parse`. The problem with the parse is if the string can't be parsed into an int, then it will throw an error. To prevent that use `int.TryParse`. Something like: `int i  = int.TryParse(TextBox.Text, out int newInt) ? newInt : 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `TextBox` is conflicting with the [`TextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) class.

Either rename your variable (which is preferred - for this exact reason), or append [`this`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this).

```
int i = int.Parse(this.TextBox.Text);
```